# jQuery with navbar (bootstraps) highlighting current link works only temporarily?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a navbar and I'm hoping to highlight the text of the current link selected. While I can get the highlighting to work using jQuery, it only highlights for about 1 second and then defaults to normal color.

My nav-bar HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
    
      <div class="container-fluid" width='300px' >
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
            
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
          <div class="thumbnail tile tile-medium tile-green">
                <a href="BJIA.html" class="fa-links">
                <h1 class="tileHeading">Home</h1>  
                <i class="fas fa-home fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
                </div>
            <div class="thumbnail tile tile-medium tile-green">
                <a href="about.html" class="fa-links">
                <h1 class="tileHeading">About</h1>
                <i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
                </div>
            <div class="thumbnail tile tile-medium tile-green">
                <a href="programs.html" class="fa-links">
                <h1 class="tileHeading">Programs</h1>
                <i class="fas fa-sitemap fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
                </div>
            <div class="thumbnail tile tile-medium tile-orange">
                <a href="data.html" class="fa-links">
                <h1 class="tileHeading">Data</h1>
                <i class="fas fa-database fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
                </div>
    </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  var activeNavItem = $('.tileHeading');

  activeNavItem.click(function(){
    activeNavItem.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');  
  });
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.tileHeading {
    font-size:28px !important;
}
.tileHeading.active {
  background-color: red
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: why you are not using `default navbar` template of bootstrap 4?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that would cause the styling to revert.  Your logic is removing the active class from all tileHeadings, before putting it on the specific one that was clicked.  Looking at your markup I don't see anything that would cause side effects of executing that logic multiple times for one click either.  Is this logic in any sort of framework like react/angular/vue?  When it happens, if you inspect the elements, is the class gone?

Comment: Unless bootstrap is also trying to toggle classes and you are conflicting with it

Comment: i'm using this example from 'metro-boostrap' for the navbar icons: https://talkslab.github.io/metro-bootstrap/components.html

Comment: I think what is happening is the page is re-loading after link is clicked.. and then the highlighting dissapears. But I thought that's what the page-ready function should take care of?

Comment: Oh, that's a very good point.  Your links are actually going to other pages, not to same page links using #section format.  Yeah, that's extremely likely what is going on.